# Batch File Recursively Rename files

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

Hi another poster npocmaka created below rename script which works well for single directory. Anybody know how to make this recursive and still use Cmd bat file

Changing line with a /r under EnableDelayedExplansion to
"for /r %%a in (*%extension%) do (" works but it
produces a

```
C:\temp\RenameMyJpgs.bat(24, 1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: File not found
```

Thanks

Alan

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    set "extension=jpg"
    set "directory=c:\temp"

    pushd "%directory%"

    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for %%a in (*%extension%) do (
        for /f %%# in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %%a') do set "cdate=%%#"
        echo ren "%%a" "!cdate!%%~xa"
    )

    rem cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
    exit /b %errorlevel%
    @if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
var file=ARGS.Item(0);

var d1=FSOObj.GetFile(file).DateCreated;

d2=new Date(d1);
var year=d2.getFullYear();
var mon=d2.getMonth();
var day=d2.getDate();
var h=d2.getHours();
var m=d2.getMinutes();
var s=d2.getSeconds();
var ms=d2.getMilliseconds();

if (mon<10){mon="0"+mon;}
if (day<10){day="0"+day;}
if (h<10){h="0"+h;}
if (m<10){m="0"+m;}
if (s<10){s="0"+s;}
if (ms<10){ms="00"+ms;}else if(ms<100){ms="0"+ms;}

WScript.Echo(""+year+mon+day+h+m+s+ms);
```

Comment: does changing to `cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %%~fa'` work?

Comment: Thanks Stephan I think it was related to  test files i was using . when i moved to a clean directory and test files it ran without error. Your addition worked just as well. I can get filenaming to work recursively but my last step must  mov the files from subdirectory to a Root directory. Can i replace ren "%%a" "!cdate!%%~xa" with a line to rename and move at same time . Can i merge destination and "!cdate!%%~xa". Thanks for your help

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `move /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output.

Comment: If you changed the the `FOR` command to use the `/R` option and any of the folder paths or file names have spaces in them you would get that error because the argument is not quoted when the cscript is executed.

Comment: I managed to resolve . I added below to code to do a copy to single dir after rename      pushd c:\temp\files
       for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do (
          COPY "%%a" "c:\temp\newfiles\%%~nxa"
           )  
           popd

Comment: Thanks Squashman for advice that explains a lot. Compo I know i might seem lazy but I haven't scripted in quite a while and the project is urgent. So apologies for looking for a short cut . I tried move and robocopy but they failed. I kept getting syntax error> adding another pop and push did the job . Thanks All for help

Comment: new problem on this. I run it on newly transferred FTP files. When i run script creation date for file name 01.25.36[A][0@0][0] made on  11/02/2021 20:11 converts to "20210111201148000.jpg" which is supposed to be year+mon+day+h+m+s+ms but month is wrong. I dont want to just +1 it to get 2 . Can anyone see issue thanks

Comment: i am aware the creation date is changed depending on move copy but the Month should still be correct as Feb 02 yes?